# Zend-framework 2 setTemplete

Tags: zend-framework2

i'm new to zendframework 2 and I have problem,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbv2B.jpg

What can cause such a mistake when I want to go another page?

Answer (score 0):

Its a spelling mistake.

Is should be `setTemplate()` rather than `setTemplete()`.

Note: Please, from next time just add the error message in the question itself. The provided link may expire one day and the question will be left meaningless.

Happy Coding!!!